# Netbeans glassfish System.out.println() displaying too much info

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, output

When my `System.out.println("Hello");` function is called, normally it used to display "Hello" in the `glassfish` domain server log.

I accidentally clicked a line and made a program counter on my script.

I wasn't sure how to get rid of it, so when I finally managed to find the setting to remove it,

I had accidentally managed to ruin my output.

I have no idea what I did, but now when I run that same System.out.println("Hello"); command, I get this:

```
[2016-08-28T21:24:02.715+0900] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=63 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1472387042715] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hello]]
```

Please help.  I don't want this mess, I just want it to say "Hello" again, and nothing more.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The above output is correct. That is what the GlassFish logger outputs by default. Your `System.out.println("Hello");` is passing `Hello` to the logger and the logger is printing out that message in its normal format.

If you open your GlassFish `server.log` you will see that every message is formatted like this.

The reason why this is happening is because the `stdout` and `stderr` are both passed through the logger.